# передать имя пользователя как значение по умолчанию в models.py

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование

Хотелось бы сделать так,чтобы по умолчанию значение в одного из полей модели записывалось имя пользователя.

```
class ComentModel(models.Model):
    text= models.CharField(max_length=1000000)
    username=models.CharField(max_length=1000) #тут должно быть имяпользователя
    post=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def publish(self):
       self.save()
```

Как это можно реализовать?
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать параметр [default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#default)

```
class ComentModel(models.Model):
        text= models.CharField(max_length=1000000)
        username=models.CharField(max_length=1000, default='<username>') #тут должно быть имя пользователя
        post=models.CharField(max_length=100)
        def publish(self):
           self.save()
```